# Condition AND at the same field cakephp 2.5

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

hi i would like to get this condition in find function for the same field:
Etudiant.specialite'='CL3 PN and Etudiant.specialite'='CI2'
i tried this code but i don't get both i only get the first one:

```
$etudiants = $this->Notemission->Etudiant->find('list',array('conditions'=> array('Etudiant.specialite'=>'CL3 PN'), array('Etudiant.specialite'=>'CI1')));
```

i also tried this code :

```
$etudiants = $this->Notemission->Etudiant->find('list',array('conditions'=> array('Etudiant.specialite'=>'CL3 PN'),array('conditions'=> array('Etudiant.specialite'=>'CI1'))));
```

Comment: How can one and the same column hold two different values at the same time?

Comment: Presumably looking for all the records that have either one value there or the other?

Comment: Possible, but the title as well as the questions says "_and_"...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$etudiants = $this->Notemission->Etudiant->find('list',array('conditions'=> array('AND' => array('Etudiant.specialite'=>'CL3 PN', 'Etudiant.specialite'=>'CI1'))));
```

But in your case, i think that you're trying to get either value, do using 'OR' should return records corresponding to either the first or second condition:

```
$etudiants = $this->Notemission->Etudiant->find('list',array('conditions'=> array('OR' => array('Etudiant.specialite'=>'CL3 PN', 'Etudiant.specialite'=>'CI1'))));
```